# How to accept a PostgreSQL database quantity in a php script?

Tags: php, psql

This is the simple snippet of code that I'm trying to edit for a school project. The problem as far as I can understand, is that its fetching the quantity right but it may not be getting stored in the variable $quantity. I've tried debugging it to no success. Also, The simple addition is giving bizarre results.
Please help. The code is as follows

```
<?php
    include("DB.php");

    $id = $_POST["flower_id"];
    $add_quantity = $_POST["quantity"];

    echo "FlowerID";
    echo $id;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Add Quantity";
    echo $add_quantity;
    echo "<br>";

    $con = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=kruttika user=kruttika");
    $quantity = pg_query("select quantity from inventory where flower_id='$id'");
    $new = $quantity;
    echo "Fetched Quantity";
    echo $new;
    echo "<br>";

    if(!$con)
      echo "Error<br>"; 
    else
    {
        $new_quantity = $new + $add_quantity;
        echo "Total Quantity";
        echo $new_quantity;
        echo "<br>";
        $sql = "update inventory set quantity=$new_quantity where flower_id='$id'";
        echo "SQL injected";
        echo $sql;
        echo "<br>";
        $result=pg_query($sql);
    }
    echo $result;
    echo "<br>";
    //echo "<script>location.href=\"adminindex.html\"</script>";
    ?>
```

Comment: use `var_dump($quantity)` after you executed the query, you will see whats wrong :)

Comment: Thanks, trying this! Will update

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is:

```
$quantity = pg_query("select quantity from inventory where flower_id='$id'");
```

[`pg_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) doesn't return the actual value, it returns a [`pg_fetch_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-result.php).

You must fetch the result to get the desidered value. See the examples on the documentation linked above.